# A question about a little implication in the justification of RSA cipher

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Incomplete Proof here:

[First Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4okd.png)

[Second Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Cbe.png)

I am trying to understand how they conclude $q \mid M$ from $M < pq.$ Occurs in the Second Part. Been on it for awhile now. Still don't get it. Please, elaborate on this.